# ActivityForResult to Gallery for another activity

Tags: android

I have 2 activities and I want to move from the first one to the gallery with avtivity4result, and when an image is picked, i want to move to the second activity.
It is like activity for result but it returns to the second activity.
I have been looking all over the internet to find it but nothing is working so I was hoping that you can help me.
This is activity 1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

The problem is when I pick a picture, it goes back to the first activity and not to the second one as I want it to be.
Thanks for the help :P

Comment: If you want to return to an Activity before this one, you could always finish() the activity that you return to from the startActivityForResult.

Comment: But I dont wanna return to the previous activity. The first activity is the first activity launched, and from there by clicking a button it moves to the gallery and then I want it to go to the second activity with the data of the image. How do i do it?

Comment: You'll just pass it along immediately to the next activity and a couple others have already chimed in below to provide some guidance on how to go about doing that.  It will look as though it is doing exactly as you are intending in the end.  Or start up the Activity you want to return to and then have the return in there instead, which will be the initialization of your picker for the gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to implement this method that will call back when you return to the first `Activity` from the `Gallery` and then you can start the second `Activity` ,  feed me back

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    // here your image that you get from gallery 
    Uri photoUri = data.getData();
    intent.putExtra("KEY", photoUri.getPath());
startActivity(intent);
 }
```

and try this code to get the Bitmap from Uri

```
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(yourUri));
        yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks but if i do it then how can i move the data that i recieved from the activity4result to the second activity through the intent?
In this case i want to send the image from the activity4result to the second activity, so it is possible to send a whole bitmap with the intent and then to get it in the second activity?

Comment: as i mention in answer the data object contain the value of the Uri that you are selected and you can put it as extra in intent to send it to another activity and in the second activity you will be able to get this value and deal with it

Comment: If i do this: i.putExtra("image", data.getData());
How do i recieve it in the second activity? It crashes every time..

Comment: yes putExtra method will help you to transfer data between the Activities

Comment: This is what i send:
i.putExtra("image", data.getData().toString());                     
---------------------------------------------------------------
And this is in the second activity (something here crashes):
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(i.getExtras().getString("image"));
Bitmap bmp = null;
try { bmp = (MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), myUri)); }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      iv1.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Comment: Sorry it is so messed up ;\

Comment: are you declare i as getIntent()?

Comment: Yes, this way: Intent i = getIntent();

Comment: look edit answer  , the code to get the bitmap from uri

Comment: You i do.. I dont understand what the problem is :(

Comment: i think it second problem if , my first answer solve your first problem accept it and post new question with the second problem with your new code

Answer (score 0):

The call `startActivityForResult` returns immediately. When you pick an image, it will call the `onActivityResult` function which you need to implement in your activity. Inside that function you can create the second activity.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
}
```